# How to document a Map with Enum as key entry?

Tags: enums, spring-restdocs

I am doing documentation for a REST service that returns this kind of JSON:

```
{
  "CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP" : {
    "keyType" : "RSA",
    "canGenerateKey" : false,
    "canEncryptDecrypt" : true,
    "canSignVerify" : false,
    "canWrapSecretKeys" : true,
    "canWrapPrivateKeys" : false,
    "canDerive" : false,
    "canDigest" : false,
    "minKeySize" : 512,
    "maxKeySize" : 16384
  },
  "CKM_SHA384" : {
    "canGenerateKey" : false,
    "canEncryptDecrypt" : false,
    "canSignVerify" : false,
    "canWrapSecretKeys" : false,
    "canWrapPrivateKeys" : false,
    "canDerive" : false,
    "canDigest" : true,
    "minKeySize" : 0,
    "maxKeySize" : 0
  }
}
```

This represents a `Map<Mechanism, MechanismInfo>` where `Mechanism` is an enum and `MechanismInfo` a POJO.

I want to document *only the fields of the `MechanismInfo` class* regardless of `Mechanism` with the constraint that `keyType` attribute can be `null` and then not present in the response. All other attributes are either integers or boolean and will have a default value.

Here are a part of my Junit 5 test:

```
this.webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(applicationContext)
  .configureClient()
  .filter(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation)
    .operationPreprocessors()
    .withResponseDefaults(prettyPrint()))
  .build();
(...)
webTestClient
  .get().uri("/tokens/{id}/mechanisms", TOKEN_TEST)
  .exchange()
  .expectStatus().isOk()
  .expectBody(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<Mechanism, MechanismInfo>>() {
  })
  .consumeWith(document(
   "get_mechanisms"
  ));
```

Could someone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As i finally found how to address this, I post how I did.
The main point is the modification of the content of the request before its documentation as described in [Spring REST Docs documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/#customizing-requests-and-responses).
So, I created my own `OperationPreprocessor` to modify the response, taking advantage of the built-in `ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor` which requires only to implement the `ContentModifier` interface. The idea was to be able to extract a unique value that I knew it was always there.

Here is what it looks like:

```java
private final class MechanismsExtract implements ContentModifier {
  @Override
  public byte[] modifyContent(byte[] originalContent, MediaType contentType) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
      Map<String, LinkedHashMap> map = objectMapper.readValue(originalContent, Map.class);
      final LinkedHashMap mechanismInfo = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(
          key -> key.getKey().equals(Mechanism.CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN.name())
        )
        .map(
          Map.Entry::getValue
        )
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow();

      return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(mechanismInfo);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      return originalContent;
    }
  }
}
```

then when documenting:

```java
(...)
  .consumeWith(document(
    "get_mechanisms",
    // Output is limited to chosen mechanisms for documentation readability reasons
    Preprocessors.preprocessResponse(
      new ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor(
        new MechanismsExtract()
      )
    ),
    relaxedResponseFields(
      fieldWithPath(NAME).description(DESCRIPTION),
      (...)
    )
    (...)
  )
(...)
```